# Styling The <li> vs. the <a>

Tags: html, css, navigation

I realize these questions may be more of opinion based, but I am looking for what the industry standard best practices are considered to be:

1) Given responsive design and collapsing menus and such, does it make sense to style a `nav` or `nav menu` element with a fixed height?

2) Within the `nav`, is it best to style the `li` or the `a` surrounding the link or is it more personal preference?

Comment: I would say that both of these questions come down entirely to personal preference and the requirements of your design.

Comment: @JonUleis I've been dealing a lot with flex-box recently, but I'm still finding that it's very difficult (requires more code) to give it it's responsive elements.  In place of that people seem to be leaving their nav heights open and using the padding and margin to give it its height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an opinionated question, so here is my opinionated answer:

> 1) Given responsive design and collapsing menus and such, does it make sense to style a nav or nav menu element with a fixed height?

Sure, why not? Google's [Material Design](https://material.io/guidelines/) includes a toolbar of fixed height (64px in large screen, 56px in smaller screens).

> 2) Within the nav, is it best to style the li or the a surrounding the link or is it more personal preference?

This is very subjective. Others, like Bootstrap [style `a`s over `li`s](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#content), when others, like Material Design Lite, [don't use anchors at all](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#menus-section).